# How to call the Search bar from homepage to all other pages in Magento 1.9?

Tags: php, xml, magento, magento-1.9

My Search bar is currently on my homepage(http://www.ashvinrx.com/magento/index.php/).
 
block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"/>

I want to make the search bar appear on my 'newproducts' page (http://www.ashvinrx.com/magento/index.php/newproducts).Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code also in phtml file.

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml')->tohtml(); ?>
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much. And how do I add this search bar to my category pages(.html pages). Where do I find them?

Comment: You can add the same code to this file :- "app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/template/catalog/category/view.phtml"

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is cms page.

you can add this code in that page `{{block type="core/template" name="top.search" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml"}}`

and search bar will appear on that page. and if you want to display this in any specific place let me know i will guide you with this.

Comment: It's not a cms page. I added this code <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml')->tohtml(); ?> in 2columns.phtml page and it worked. The only problem now is positioning. Can you help me out please?

Comment: yes sure, but first of all it's not good idea to add this in 2columns.phtml file it's conman layout file.

Please let me know where you want to add this search box i will suggest you best possible place to add code.

Also as it's not cms page then it must have layout file you can add below code to it's layout xml file.

<block type="core/template" name="top.search" as="topsearch" template="catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml">

and add <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topsearch'); ?> into your phtml file where you want to display this.

Comment: You can have a look here : http://prntscr.com/f8tt7m . I want to place it in either of those boxes. And also,the search bar should be persistent on all of my category(html) pages including this current page i.e.'Latest products' page.

Comment: you can add below code.  

<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml')->tohtml(); ?>  

into this file.  
"app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/template/catalo‌​g/product/list.phtml" and adjust it's place as per your design. using this code into this file it will appear all category page for sure.

Answer (score 0):

For Magento recent versions try this format below:

```
 <?php echo $this>getLayout()createBlock('Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template')->setTemplate('Magento_Search::form.mini.phtml')->toHtml() ?>
```